# How to align subscripted annotations with axis labels in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

This question is a follow-up to my earlier [question about how to align annotations with axis labels in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285198/how-to-align-annotations-with-axis-labels-in-pgfplots). The accepted solution works perfectly, but I've run into a further alignment problem when the annotation includes subscripts (which I did not consider in my original post). Then the baseline of the annotation does not match the baseline of the axis label.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=s,
  xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,
  xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
  clip=false]
  \addplot[color=red] table {
    0.1 0.9
    0.9 0.2
  };  
\end{axis}
\draw[blue] (s.outer south west) -- (s.outer south east); % help line
\node[anchor=south west] at (s.outer south west) {(a) $A_y$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

So my question is: How do I get the baseline of the annotation to be aligned with the baseline of the axis label? (In other words, I would like the solution to work even in the case where the axis label has a subscript also.)

(I am aware of and often use the `subfig` package, but for this particular case I want to avoid it.)

Comment: Add `xlabel style={text depth=0.25em},` or some other proper length depending on the common subscript size to align with the annotation.

Comment: @percusse: As far as I can tell from playing around with the value of `text depth`, this simply moves the annotation up and down, but does not align the baselines properly. Is there a solution that does not require me to specify a fixed value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the anchors `base` and `base west` in order to respect the baseline:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=s,
  xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,
  xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
  xlabel style={name=s-label},
  clip=false]
  \addplot[color=red] table {
    0.1 0.9
    0.9 0.2
  };  
\end{axis}
\draw[blue] (s.outer south west) -- (s.outer south east); % help line
\node[anchor=base west] at (perpendicular cs: 
        vertical line through={(s.outer south west)}, 
        horizontal line through={(s-label.base)})
        {(a) $A_y$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The items are

- assign a label to `xlabel`
- use the `perpendicular cs` in order to determine the position
- use the `base` `anchor`s in order to align them